# Windows 10 missing taskbar icons

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, icons

How can I restore the icons for the Windows App Store applications?

Recently icons for Windows App Store applications do not show anymore. Here's an example:

[image: Example of missing icons. Edge, Outlook, Messenger and Settings icons are not showing]

I have tried various ways to reset the thumbnails cache but nothing have helped. I have also run the troubleshooter in Windows 10.

I am using `Windows 10 Version 1709 (OS Build 16299.125)`

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Some Windows 10 UWP icons not displaying on search, or in settings](https://superuser.com/questions/1319157/some-windows-10-uwp-icons-not-displaying-on-search-or-in-settings).

Comment: Try restarting. Sometimes, it fixes the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. For me the solution was to uninstall Google Drive File Stream. Do you have it installed?

Also, checkout this [similar SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/1283165/uwp-icons-are-missing).

Comment: Yup, Google Drive File Stream was my issue.

Answer (score 0):

This happened when I got the new "security update" in January 2018.

What I did is use `End Task` to kill all svchost tasks in Windows Task Manager details tab.

Then i shutdown the computer and powered it on.

The icons for All Settings and Store started working again and showed pictures when I pinned them back into the taskbar.

Answer (score -1):

[Some Windows 10 UWP icons not displaying on search, or in settings](https://superuser.com/questions/1319157/some-windows-10-uwp-icons-not-displaying-on-search-or-in-settings)

Following the steps in **Issue 1: Third-party thumbnail handlers for .png** resolved the problem for me. I had installed Irfanview and set it to be the default for all images, including png files.

Note, the change did not immediately go into effect. I chose to kill and restart explorer.exe with the task manager, but a reboot would have worked just as well.

I also have google file stream installed. It does not seem to impact the issue in my case.