# Windows 10 Quiet Hours not turning on?

Tags: windows-10

as of recently, I can't turn on Windows 10's Quiet Hours setting. I click the button and it does nothing. Not really sure what other info needs to be provided but I can provide anything upon request. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** I have rebooted and tried from another user account. Neither of these allowed me to toggle Quiet Hours. `sfc /scannow` returned nothing wrong with my system.

Comment: Have you already tried to reboot the machine? Have you tried from a different profile from the same machine? Have you run `SFC /SCANNOW`? Have you checked to ensure all Windows Updates are complete just in case run and confirm and get all installed, reboot and then try again? See my answer here https://superuser.com/questions/1283165/uwp-icons-are-missing/1285465#1285465 regarding the rest of Windows 10 and keeping your settings, etc. intact as this may help as well, have you already tried that? Just to confirm, you click on it and it does not toggle from ON to OFF or vice verse, correct?

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT I have rebooted the machine, and all windows updates are complete. I'll try the rest of your suggestions now. And yes, it does not toggle from off to on.