# Windows 10 won't boot; won't get to Startup Repair/Recovery options

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, bootrepair, win10-fast-startup

I'm a db dev & vba programmer, very active on Stack Overflow, but Windows 10 boot/hardware stuff is out of my comfort zone.

I have an Acer E551 laptop with Windows 10. A few months ago it had a hard disk corrupt-sectors issue, [eventually fixed](https://superuser.com/questions/1305435/how-to-force-windows-10-reset-recovery-repair-with-only-partial-boot) (basically had to run `CHKDSK /R /F /X` a few dozen times) and it's been fine for months until now.

Now, **it again won't boot, but won't even let me get to the Windows startup options so that I can try `CHKDSK` or Safe Boot, etc.**  It just gives me the "spinning circle" and eventually a black screen with the hard drive LED solid.

- I tried leaving it on the black screen for hours; no change.
- I tried rebooting 3x holding shift (repeatedly) to force repair, and it will say it's gathering info for startup repair but again ends up on the black screen.

Sadly this is my only machine right now. I am using a USB stick with Ubuntu 17.04 running off the stick, which is the only way I can post this question.
 :-(

**Is there a way to "force" the Windows Startup Repair or Windows command prompt for other troubleshooting, perhaps via Ubuntu?**

Repair/replacement is not an option at this time. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend using a windows 10 bootable usb instead of Ubuntu so you can go in to recovery options to run chkdsk,sfc scan,restore point,startup repair etc. [Here](https://itsfoss.com/bootable-windows-usb-linux/) is a basic guide you will need another usb since you are using Ubuntu from your current one

Comment: @PloxPanda -  Excellent link thank you. I don't suppose I can double up on one USB, or use an external USB hard drive (via partition so I don't have to lose my data on the external drive)?

Comment: For the double up on one usb the process in of creating the bootable usb it will need to format it which will wipe the data and you will lose Ubuntu. I'm not too sure about partitioning the external hard drive for it though but its worth a shot!