# How do I fix icon clipping in folders?

Tags: windows-7, icons, desktop, desktop-icons

I am having an issues with images/icons clipping outside of folders. Also, icons that have transparency have white boxes around them while in folders. Here's two images showing my issue(s):

[image]

[image]

I've tried a few methods, that I found on Google, like deleting `%localappdata%/IconCache.db`, disabling `Use drop shadows for icon labels on the desktop` in Performance Options, and change icon size (which was useless). None of the solutions worked.

Please note: I am using a custom icon pack ([Super Remix Icon Packs on DeviantArt](https://niivu.deviantart.com/art/Super-Remix-Icon-Packs-725143327)) and these issues were happening even before installing the icon pack.

EDIT: After removing the icon pack I am still having issues with the white border around icons. Here's a photo showing it.

[image]

Comment: Did that before and that would only restore the unmodified dll files from before the icon pack.

Comment: To ensure you understood the icon cache solutions you read about, look at this batch script logic I saved here which you can run to perform those steps within 10 seconds or so and restart Explorer in case you missed that step: https://justpaste.it/1j1v3

Comment: Had to take ownership of said files first, then ran each command, and restarted explorer.exe. After the databases were rebuilt, it seemed like nothing changed.

Comment: This reminds me of this post I answered but for **Windows 10** https://superuser.com/questions/1283165/uwp-icons-are-missing/1286773#1286773 but it may be worth a read to you. I assume by ***"it seemed like nothing changed"*** means that that did not do anything to help resolve the problem, correct? I assume you are not willing to uninstall **Super Remix Icon Packs on DeviantArt** from this computer and then running the purge of the icon cache files, and then reinstalling the **Super Remix Icon Packs on DeviantArt** but not changing the icons as you did the first time wouldn't work, correct?

Comment: The problem with the icons clipping out of folders is fixed, but I still have the issue with icons that have transparency not displaying correctly inside of folders (The white box). There isn't a reason to have the icon pack installed besides aesthetic purposes to go along with the theme I was using with WindowBlinds from Stardock. Also running `chkdsk` is pointless as it only checks the sectors of the HDD/SSD.

Comment: Hmm, strange. But do you happen to have a solution for my white boxed icons when the area around them are supposed to be transparent?

Comment: A few ideas you'll need to test.... **1.)** as per https://i.imgur.com/cXoFOQ0.png check the #1 option there first then apply and then then check #2 and then apply and check. **2.)** as per https://i.imgur.com/6luv4FB.png check the #1 option there first then apply and then then check #2 and then apply and check. **3.)** change your desktop wallpaper to a solid color and then check to see if that clears it up. I thought there was an option for "*Web*" or "*Lock Web Items on Desktop*" that may be the culprit but I cannot find on Windows 7 but those are some other ideas for things to check.