# Windows 11 - Taskbar icons missing under specific user account

Tags: windows-11, taskbar, icons

Several questions have dealt with that error, but none of the solutions have worked for me. Some taskbar icons disappeared at some point a couple of days ago and nothing brings them back. The problem only occurs in the non-admin account on my laptop. What I tried so far:

- Install the latest Windows updates
- Uninstall the latest Windows updates
- Removed `IrisService` as indicated [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/all/fix-included-no-icons-on-task-bar-on-windows-11/9b580be3-080b-4897-a091-8aefdb6f5b6c)
- Every attempt from [here](https://windowsreport.com/windows-11-taskbar-icons-missing/) except for installing third-party software
- Set registry value according to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1283165/uwp-icons-are-missing) answer from [@Vomit IT](https://superuser.com/users/510662/vomit-it-chunky-mess-style)

Since it only occurs in the non-admin account and apparently only for Windows apps like Outlook, PowerShell, or Spotify (from the store), I suspect it has to do with a corrupted user profile. Any help is greatly appreciated since it drives me crazy.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> The problem only occurs in the non-admin account on my laptop.

This is not altogether uncommon.

There is not any tool or any normally practical way to repair a Windows user profile.

Back up the contents of this non-admin user profile, ensure the back up contains everything, delete the profile, restart and make a new user profile.

Comment: This is a work account that I used for many years... I don't even want to imagine how much time it would take to do that :(

Comment: Just back up your data (maybe an hour or two), make a new user profile (easy), and restore your data (another hour or two), and setup.  Half day or a bit more.

Comment: Do you have any insight how this can happen though? And why it only happened for that user and none other (there is another non-admin account, which is not affected)?

Comment: Some software/actions can damage a user profile. I have learned to keep organized and to not customize.

Comment: As a note of interest: I have the same problem with a completely fresh PC. It appears to be a combination of not powering down but sleeping & many virtual desktops & switching between them. At some point, first the icons get a bit garbled and later they disappear completely until I restart the PC. This is happening on my only account which is Admin.

Comment: It seems reasonable that you can create circumstances to cause this.  I use virtual machines, not virtual desktops.  Make sure all your drivers are up to date. Suspend does not cause this issue for me.